# How long does Indian visa processing take for an American born citizen of Pakistani heritage?

Tags: visas, usa, india, pakistan

I am an American born, US citizen. My parents however came over from Pakistan in the 70's and haven't been back since. They have been citizens for over 30 years.

I am going to the embassy in SF to apply for an Indian Business Visa. I have a company sponsoring me which prepared a letter. How long would it take? Does anyone have experience? Is there any chance of out right rejection? I have a flight scheduled that I would hate to cancel.

Thanks!

Comment: Indian embassy pages for [Netherlands](http://www.indianembassy.nl/eoi.php?id=Visa-Pakistani) and [Canada](http://www.cgitoronto.gov.in/eoi.php?id=Pakistani) state that processing time is a minimum of 7-8 weeks for Pakistani citizens or Persons of Pakistani origin.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply online. The embassy will not help you. The only sanctioned processor for Indian visas is CKGS (Cox & Kings Global Services). You should [start here](https://www.in.ckgs.us/visa/business-visa-getstarted).

Rumors are it can take upto six weeks. However, there is a high chance of rejection even after the six weeks have transpired.